# Unit-testing a function

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new to unit-testing. However, I need to make a test for the function below. I've done some reading but can't really get much from reading. This is what I have been able to come with but I certainly know there is more to do. Could someone tell me what i would need to do next.

```
def apply_filter(x): 
    filterer = { 
        1: 'ether proto 0x88B8', 
        2: 'tcp port 102', 
        3: 'ether proto 0x88BA' 
    } 
    return filterer.get(x, '') 



import unittest 

from new_format import apply_filter 


class test_apply_filter(unittest.TestCase): 

    def setUp(self): 
        pass 
    def tearDown(self): 
        pass 

    def test_filter_by_name(self): 
        self.assertEqual(apply_filter(1),"ether proto 0x88B8") 
        self.assertEqual(apply_filter(2),"tcp port 102") 
        self.assertEqual(apply_filter(3),"ether proto 0x88BA") 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This is a good start.. run it and see.. The next step is to add edge cases - like `apply_filter(None)`, `apply_filter(4)`, ...

Answer (score 0):

A good way to write unit tests is to write the test before writing the code, then you write the code to make the test turn green, then you clean your code. It's call TDD, Test-driven development.

You can learn more about TDD here: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)

Comment: Okay I shall check that up do you know any books or sites good to read @MaximeTurcotte

Comment: Yeah, you can read Clean Code by Robert C. Martin. This guy is a Guru for a lot of people when it comes to write quality code. It'll tell you about unit testing with TDD and how to write clean code.

Comment: Okay are there any videos that are good on youtube @MaximeTurcotte

Comment: I don't know, may be you can watch videos by Robert C. Martin, like this one: https://vimeo.com/97516288